# Removing a string within a string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I am having a string like this:

```
"welcome country !
and some texts

Keyword1:the value
keyword2: the value2"
```

I want to remove keyword on undo the corresponding checkbox and also its value using Javascript. Now i could remove the keyword while undo checkbox but not the value they have entered near the keyword.
I have tried substring functions and some other, but i couldn't fix it.

my code below:

```
$("#txtNote").val(url.replace($(this).attr("data-id") + ":", ""));
```

I just want to remove the texts immediately after the ":"

here is my entire code:

```
 if ($(this).attr("data-selected1") == "true") {
            $("#detailChronic").show();         
            $(this).attr("data-selected1", "false");
           //$(".hjk").remove(":contains('" + $(this).attr("data-id") + "')");
            var url = $.trim($("#txtNote").val());
            str = $("#txtNote").val();
            //var t = str.substring(str.indexOf(":"))
            //alert(t);
            //url = url.replace(/\s+/g, "\n");

            // $("#txtNote").val(url.replace($(this).attr("data-id") + ":", ""));
           // $("#txtNote").val(url.replace($(this).attr("data-id") + ":" + $(this).attr("data-id").value(), ""));             
            //url.replace($(this).attr("data-id") + ":", "");
            alert(url);
            var temp2 = temp1.replace(/($(this).attr("data-id"))(\:(.*))/, "");
            alert(temp2);
            var temp1 = url.replace($(this).attr("data-id"), "");

            alert(temp1);
            $("#txtNote").val(temp1);

           // $("#txtNote").val(url.replace($(this).attr("data-id") + ":" + $(this).attr("data-id").value(), ""));

                if ($("#selectedList").html() == "") {
                $("#detailChronic").hide();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please create a relevant snippet using `<>` in the editor.

Comment: Will all of your keywords be in separate line?

Comment: @leninhasda , now it is in separate line. can we remove the particular line from the string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to remove 'Keyword1:the value', then try

```js
var keyWordToRemove = 'Keyword1';
var rgxStr = keyWordToRemove + ':[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*\n';
var rgx = new RegExp(rgxStr,'g');
var text = `welcome country !
and some texts

Keyword1:the value
keyword2: the value2`;

console.log(text);

text = text.replace(rgx,"");

console.log(text);
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using regex like this

```js
var url = `welcome country !
and some texts

Keyword1:the value
keyword2: the value2`;

console.log(url.replace("Keyword1:", "test key "))
console.log(url.replace(/(Keyword1)(\:(.*))/, "$1 test value"))
```

you can replace `Keyword1` with `$(this).attr("data-id") + ":"` in your code