# How to write a JS function to remove the array of certain symbols from the string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Need to write a function, that takes two arguments:

1. the first is a string
2. the second is an array of symbols we need to exclude from the string.

As a result it should turn out as `foo('hello world', ['o']); // 'hell wrld'

Here is the example for the case if we have only one symbol to remove:

```
function foo(string, array) {
  var newString = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    newString += string[i].replace(array, '');                      
  }
  return newString; 
}

//lad up n guns bring yur friends
console.log(foo('load up on guns bring your friends',['o']));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing a string within a string using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260439/removing-a-string-within-a-string-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a regular expression and remove the unwanted characters.

```js
function foo(string, array) {
    return string.replace(new RegExp(array.join('|'), 'gi'), '');
}

console.log(foo('load up. on guns bring your friends.', ['o', 'i', '\\.']));
```

An approach without a regular expression.

```js
function replace(string, array) {
    var search = new Set(array);
    return Array.from(string, c => search.has(c) ? '' : c).join('');
}

console.log(replace('load up on guns bring your friends', ['o', 'i']));
```

Comment: This will fail if `array` contains special characters, for example: `foo('abc', ['.'])`

Comment: Thanks. But if it's possible to do the same without using regular expressions? I was trying to do with two loops - the first for array fingering , and the second - for string fingering

Comment: @holden, do you have only a single character to search for?

Comment: do you look for `'oo'`? for example or just for a single character?

Comment: No there are only single characters - the letters

Answer (score 1):

You can use for loop to loop through all replacable elements & remove matching characters using regexmatch on string

```js
function foo(string, array) {
    for(const a of array){
      let pattern = new RegExp(a, 'g');
      string = string.replace(pattern, '');
    }
        return string;   
}
console.log(foo('load up on guns bring your friends',['o','i'])); //lad up n guns bring yur friends
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by simply using regex like given below

```js
function foo(str,arr)
{
var regExp = new RegExp('['+arr.join(',')+']+','g');
console.log(str.replace(regExp, ""));
}

foo("hello world",['o'])
```